# YAML 2 quotes at the beginning of a string

Tags: php, symfony, translation, yaml

I've got a problem with the translation System of Symfony2. We are currently using YAML Files for this.

Everything works fine but when I got a string with a quote at the beginning, we get some parse errors.

Example:

my/special/key: "Button Name" is very cool

Symfony now thinks that "Button Name" is the complete string and not only a part of it. If I have only

my/special/key: Button Name is very cool

everything works fine. I also can't escape the quotes because they are visible at the website.

Any Ideas?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You have to escape it when you load and save it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YAML specifies a string with or without the double quotes. If you use the double quote version, all trailing characters are invalid syntax, because it's not a string any more but random characters without any meaning. You can escape the double quote characters with a backspace. See the [YAML specification for details](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2776092) (Number [52]).